# Azure web service not working office 365 login screen not show

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

Step 1 # Login Page Load after that I Press a Button which hit a method in login Controller name is loginProcess

Step 2# when login Process hit it's call a method SignIn

Step 3# SignIn method it's call Azure Authentication

I am having problem when I publish my web on azure my signin method did not work
when I published my web on azure office 365 login popup was not loaded. while on local host it was loaded when I call my signin method. what was the reason of this behavior after publishing web on Azure.

```
  [HttpGet]
            public  ActionResult Login()
            {
                var DashboardDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                ViewBag.Date = DashboardDate;         
                return View();
            } 

  [HttpGet]
        public async Task <ActionResult>LoginProcess()
        {
            try
            {
              if (await new ServiceAPIConnection().SignIn())
                {




  }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //new ExceptionHandling().InsertErrorLog(ex);
                GlobalMembers.DynamicDialog("Your credentials did not work or the service is down. Please try again." + "|Login: 03"); 

this is Sign in method 

public async Task<bool> SignIn()
        {
            try
            {
                SignOut();
                 AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(GlobalSettings.todoListResourceId, GlobalSettings.clientId, redirectURI, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always));        
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result.AccessToken))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                userName = result.UserInfo.DisplayableId.ToString().Trim();
                userToken = result.AccessToken.Trim();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }


            return true;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include details about what is not working. You simply mentioned that your `signup method did not work`. Please tell us what you're expecting and what is the actual result you're getting.

Comment: when I published my web on azure office 365 login popup was not loaded. while on local host it was loaded when I call my signin method. what was the reason of this behavior after publishing web on Azure.

Comment: It seems there is no issue with you mentioned code. But you could debug it with following ways: 1)  [remove debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug)  2) use fiddler to catch the request. You also could refer to the [WebApp Sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) to check whether there is any restriction in WebApp in your project.